# What NSDateFormat is 1991-07-26T05:45:50.163

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm having trouble with setting a date formatter as its returning null.  Based on other questions online, I now that the format could be culprit however I'm having trouble deciphering what this timestamp is:

```
1991-07-26T05:45:50.163
```

I've tried the following:

```
[self.dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
[self.dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS"];
[self.dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

and also...

```
[self.dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
```

but still no luck!

Here is my code:

```
self.dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [self.dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:SS"];
        NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        date  = [self.dateformatter dateFromString:timestamp];
        NSLog(@"Date variable now reads as: %@", date);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one didn't work but thank you

Comment: Drop the `'`, use the `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSS`.

Comment: @Itachi No, the `'` is required around the `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1991-07-26T05:45:50.163 for this

Use Below date format :

`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"`